# Bad class file failed the ant build

Tags: java, ant

I just changed `jdk` from `1.6` to `1.8` and when making an new `ant` build, it gives such error messages:

```
[javac] /usr/workspace/test/src/JsonString.java:7: cannot access java.lang.Object
[javac] bad class file: java/lang/Object.class(java/lang:Object.class)
[javac] class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0
[javac] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
[javac] public class JsonString {
[javac]
```

This is weird. the `Object` class should be in `java1.8`, how could it be bad? Do anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You are mixing Java versions, you are using `javac` from JDK 6 with the standard library from Java 8. Make sure your Java setup is correct (check `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME`).

Comment: my `javac` and `java_home` are all pointed to `java1.8`

Comment: What does `java -version` show?

Comment: @Liquid it seems `javac` is 1.8 but `java` is 1.6, just double check which versions you actually get with `java -version` and `javac -version`

Comment: I reset the '/etc/profile' and use a newest java version. The problem solved somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that the `javac` task is not using a specific compiler other than the default one. This can occur if you're setting the `executable` attribute to fork a specific compiler (along with `fork="yes"`), as mentioned in the [task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html):

> **executable**
>
> Complete path to the javac executable to use in case of fork="yes". Defaults to the compiler of the Java version that is currently running Ant. Ignored if fork="no".
>   Since Ant 1.6 this attribute can also be used to specify the path to the executable when using jikes, jvc, gcj or sj.

If you're just calling `javac` without specifying any external compiler, then Ant would use the compiler that comes with the Java version that is running Ant. And from the error message, it's clearly using the Java 1.6 compiler (for which classfiles have version 50.0). Ant normally runs using the `java` executable found in the `PATH` environment variable. So make sure that the first Java directory that is specified in the `PATH` variable is Java 1.8.

Ideally you should have `JAVA_HOME` set to the path of Java 1.8, and have `PATH` refer to `JAVA_HOME` itself so that both point to the same installation.

```
JAVA_HOME -> /path_to_jdk1.8
PATH -> %JAVA_HOME%;...;/path_to_some_other_jdk
```